# Do I require airport transit visa

Tags: visas, transit, airports

I am flying from London to Riyadh via Frankfurt. Do I require airport transit visa at Frankfurt. I'm a Saudi citizen and I have UK BRP.

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket?

Answer (score 2):

If both flights are connecting and on the same ticket, then no, Saudi citizens don’t need an airport transit visa as long as they stay airside. This is valid for all Schengen countries.

If the flights are on separate tickets, then you will need a full Schengen visa, not just an ATV.